# Live Audio Stream using Java

Tags: java, sockets, browser, real-time, audio-streaming

I'm trying to do the following task :

Get mic input in PC, transmit it real time to my webserver, and then broadcast the audio stream real time so that a person accessing my webpage could listen to the stream realtime.
I'm using a java application in the PC to get the mic input.

I've made the following attempts :

1. Opening a socket connection to the server machine hosting the web application, transferring the captured audio in byte chunks.
2. And receiving these bytes using a java application in the server machine, and then continuously updating a file as the bytes come in.
3. I'm using a VLC player plugin in my webpage, and I've set its target to the above file which is being continuously updated, so that we can get realtime streaming.

This approach seems to **fail** due to **synchronization and latency problems**

- VLC stops playing the stream after a few seconds (I'm assuming the reason to be the bytes not having arrived on time)

I've checked several sources, and other questions on stackoverflow too, but I haven't come across any solid ideas for an implementation.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this direction, Thank you.